# Split string by repeating keyword

Tags: c#

I have a repeating text file that is similar to this, which I am looking to break up into individual files based on the 'Tx' indicator .... Any thoughts on how I could achieve this?

```
Tx1
some data 
some data
Tx2
some data 
some data
Tx3
some data 
some data
```

Comment: Are the `Tx#`s important or just your split points?

Comment: How big is the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.Load a the file contents to memory as a string

2.Use RegEx to split

```
string[] lines = Regex.Split(str, "Tx^[0-9]");
```

3.Save each line different file

Comment: Probably want to include a line start and end in case the data happens to have a Tx5 in it for some reason. Probably should also use `[0-9]+` to support Tx numbers >=10.

Comment: Why read the whole text file into memory? This is potentially very wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider a potentially more efficient implementation that generates files on-line without having to commit all of the chunks into memory.

Given some `IEnumerator`:

```
static IEnumerator<string> DataStream()
{
    var original = "Tx1\nsome data1\nsome data2\nTx2\nsome data3\nsome data4\nTx3\nsome data5\nsome data6\nTx4\nTx5";
    Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}", original);
    return ((IEnumerable<string>) original.Split('\n')).GetEnumerator();
}
```

You can construct all of your files in a single pass. Set up some [predicate function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that returns true for your `Tx^[0-9]` case (note this can be replaced easily with a regular expression):

```
Func<string, bool> isDelimiterString = token => 
    token.Length > 2 
    && token[0] == 'T'
    && token[1] == 'x';
```

An algorithm dealing directly with the `IEnumerator` is:

```
var enumerable = DataStream();
var enumeratorHasNext = enumerable.MoveNext();
while (enumeratorHasNext)
{
    var delimiter = enumerable.Current;
    using (var file = new StreamWriter(delimiter + ".txt"))
    {
        enumeratorHasNext = enumerable.MoveNext();
        while (enumeratorHasNext && !isDelimiterString(enumerable.Current))
        {
            file.WriteLine(enumerable.Current);
            enumeratorHasNext = enumerable.MoveNext();
        }
    }
}
```

I put a working example [on Github](https://github.com/JLospinoso/q37220367).